# How to write spring test suite of multiple tests and run selective tests?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

I have many spring test methods  in a test class.  i want to run only selective tests. So i want to create a test suite in same class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/testApplicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class TestersChoice  { 


@Test
@Transactional
public void testAddAccount(){        
  ///do something ....
}  


@Test
@Transactional
public void testDeleteAccount(){        
  ///do something ....
}   

@Test
@Transactional
public void testReadAccount(){        
  ///do something ....
}
```

}

If I run this Class TestersChoice all tests will run!  I just want to run testReadAccount not the rest.  I want to create suite to run selective tests. (I want to avoid deleting @Test above test methods to achieve this)
Something like in jUnit testcase . This is what i was able to do by  extending TestersChoice class to   TestCase  and inserting this method:

```
public static TestSuite suite(){
      TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
       suite.addTest(new TestersChoice("testDeleteAccount"));
      return suite;
}
```

But as now I am not extending TestCase so I am unable to add TestersChoice instance to suite!

How to run selective tests?

Comment: How do you run your tests? Eclipse? Maven? Something else?

Comment: I run them on eclipse but once all test suits completed i have to eventually deploy on maven using surefire plugin.

Comment: Doing some research i see that test suits are possible in spring-test if you add multiple test classes to suit , but can't find anything yet how to run selective tests in a test file!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, can't you just right-click a method and run it?

Comment: You can right click the test method, and run as JUnit Test

Answer (score 1):

if what you want is to group your tests then the issue is not with spring-test but rather with JUnit where grouping tests is not possible. Consider switching to TestNG (also supported by spring OOTB).

TestNG is built on JUnit but a lot more powerfull: See [comparison](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/).

[Grouping](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) is easy.

regards,
Stijn

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's `IfProfileValue` (if you are always using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`) and then tests will only run if you specify particular system properties using `-D<propertyname>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Ignore` on each method whom you do not want to execute. Taking your example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/testApplicationContext.xml"}) @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true) public class TestersChoice  { 


@Test  @Transactional @Ignore public void testAddAccount(){           ///do something .... }  


@Test @Transactional @Ignore public void testDeleteAccount(){          ///do something .... }   

@Test @Transactional public void testReadAccount(){           ///do something .... }
```

All methods marked as `@Ignore` will not be executed